# Convergence of sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, self-study, central-limit-theorem

$X$ is the number of heads we got after tossing $n$ fair coins.

My question is: $P(X< \frac{n}{2}+\sqrt{n})$ if $n \to \infty$?

I tried to apply CLT like this:

$P(\frac{X-\frac{n}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n(2n-1)}}{2}}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{n(2n-1)}})\to \phi(\frac{2}{\sqrt{n(2n-1)}})$ as $n \to  \infty$. 
Which yields $1/2$ to this probability.

I am not at all sure what I was doing was  right, please help! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_n$ is a **Binomial** $(n, p=1/2)$ random variable, the sum of $n$ independent Bernoullis, with $E(X_n) = n/2, \text{Var}(X_n) = n/4$. So the pivot

$$Z_n = \frac {X_n - n/2}{\sqrt {n/4}}\xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$$

by the CLT.  Therefore

$$\Pr\left(X_n \leq \frac n2 + \sqrt n\right) = \Pr\left(\frac {X_n - n/2}{\sqrt {n/4}}\leq \frac {\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n/4}}\right)$$

$$=\Pr\left(\frac {X_n - n/2}{\sqrt {n/4}}\leq 2\right)\rightarrow \Phi(2)$$

where $\Phi()$ is the standard normal CDF. Then we look up the tables.